# Comentario duplicado/rude

Tags: suporte

Nesta pergunta: "[Validação de objeto de negócio evitando/reduzindo uso de if's e else's](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22184/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-objeto-de-neg%C3%B3cio-evitando-reduzindo-uso-de-ifs-e-elses/22196?noredirect=1#comment40201_22196)"
o OP comentou abaixo da sua pergunta com mais detalhes sobre um comentário e postou exatamente o mesmo comentário poucos segundos depois na resposta que postei.

Eu sinalizei o comentário por achar desnecessário uma vez que eu ja' havia sido notificado quando ao primeiro comentário e achei rude especialmente pelo

```
"Como dito anteriormente:"
```

O qual aparentemente um tom seco indicando que deveria ter lido o comentário anterior antes de responder 41 minutos antes de tal comentário existir.

Eu sinalizei como não construtivo, mas não sei se meu julgamento e' valido.

Comment: Conforme já respondido pelo @bfavaretto, não creio que a ideia era ser rude, mas apenas de notificá-lo a respeito do comentário feito em outro lugar. Apaguei o comentário justamente porque ele já havia cumprido o propósito e ficaria redundante. Entendo que o comentário parece "seco", mas considere esta é uma característica da forma escrita.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu rejeitei a sinalização (e o utluiz em seguida excluiu o comentário) pois não o considerei desreipetoso, mesmo que redundante. Acredito que o autor só queria ter certeza de que você visse a informação adicional, e fosse notificado por isso. (Aliás, tem certeza de que foi notificado do primeiro comentário? Pelo que vejo, não deveria).