# Sobre respostas e comentários rudes

Tags: debate

Eu mesmo aprendi no tapa a melhorar minhas perguntas aqui pra não receber resposta atravessada e negativo sem explicação.

Sei que ninguém é pago pra responder, então, não precisa tratar o usuário como se fossemos parte de um time de *customer service* também, mas eu já me senti acanhado (por falta de outra palavra) por fazer perguntas e receber respostas rudes.

O ponto é: será que não estamos limitando nosso alcance ao assumir que o usuário sabe como fazer uma pergunta aqui? Se cultivássemos uma cultura de um pouco mais de paciência e compreensão de como alguém chega aqui pela primeira vez, explicar/ensinar como melhorar a pergunta nos comentários, não melhoraríamos a nossa comunidade?

> Não vou colocar exemplos no post pra não gerar controvérsia ou falar
>   que é indireta.

Comment: Acho que isso já foi discutido por cá... E acho que a conclusão é sempre a mesma, claro que sim! Mas depois dai a acontecer de facto alguma coisa já vai uma distância.

Comment: Você precisa ver os dois lados. Muita gente chega aqui, recebe dicas e instruções e não quer nem saber de aprender. Alguns são até grossos e rudes com quem tenta orientar. Infelizmente, com o tempo, isso acaba fazendo alguns usuários veteranos ficarem mais "cascudos" e "secos", não necessariamente rudes. Agora se você acha que algum tipo de tratamento extrapolou o limite da educação, sempre é possível sinalizar o comentário como rude ou direto pra um moderador, dependendo da gravidade.

Comment: [SEMPRE PRESUMA BOA INTENÇÃO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), no entanto se for algo ofensivo mesmo ou até "abusivo" use o link lado de uma bandeira (chamado sinalizar) e aguarde o moderador intermediar.[

Comment: Ótimos pontos. Eu queria justamente chamar a atenção dos usuários veteranos pro debate e pra ajudar no policiamento da comunidade. Gosto da atitude e das recomendações do link que o @GuilhermeNascimento mencionou.

Comment: Uma coisa que acontece muito é da gente falar algo e já ser levado como "rude". É preciso entender que estamos aqui pra ser objetivos, perguntar e responder, trazer conteúdo, não pra ficar mandando beijos, abraços, risadas e emojis.

Comment: @JorgeB. um exemplo de situação passada (sobre comentários): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1593/3635

Comment: Você está coberto de razão

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Lembrando que o be-nice vale também, e talvez até mais, para os usuários experientes reagindo a perguntas e comentários de quem chega. Serve para combater a reação imediata de "preguiça", "dever de casa", etc, etc.

Comment: @Gabe claro que sim, a questão é que geralmente as pessoas veteranas são mais sugestíveis a aceitar criticas, isso porque já conhecem a casa, só que sempre reforços aos novatos, porque já vi muitos virando inimigos de outros usuários por pouca coisa. Não vou citar exemplos para que a coisa toda aqui não perca o foco, mesmo que só sendo exemplos. Ainda sim como **eu já disse**, *eu* concordo, vale para ambos lados.

Comment: @LINQ entendo o seu ponto, mas a linha aí é tênue, ao meu ver. Por isso levantei o assunto. Não é pra enfeitar o comentário, concordo, mas não custa nada ser amigável já que a intenção é ajudar. O conhecimento e a objetividade não podem ser confundidos com ironia, arrogância e condescendência.

Comment: A questão é que é característico da forma escrita ser impessoal e, aqui no site, isso parece ter sido um grande um problema.

Comment: @LINQ podia até ser uma característica mas antes da internet, ao meu ver. Acho que as novas ferramentas de escrita e comunicação, redes sociais, emojis, emoticons e etc. estão tentando transformar isso.

Comment: Sim, mas o nossa intenção é justamente ser impessoal. Nós queremos isso, o StackOverflow não é uma rede social. Isso que eu quero dizer, estamos aqui justamente para sermos impessoais e muita gente tem levado isso pro lado da rudez, exatamente por causa disto que tu citou: "emojis, emoticons, redes sociais".

Comment: @LINQ pro meu próprio entendimento, quando você diz "nós queremos isso", o "nós" seria a comunidade? É algo que já foi debatido ou é uma diretiva do SO em geral?

Comment: É um dos "princípios" do SO. Ter mais foco no conteúdo e menos nas pessoas.

Comment: @LINQ vc tem alguma referência ou link falando sobre isso pra me mandar? Não consegui achar na "Ajuda"

Comment: Vou te dizer que infelizmente aqui se tem muito a cultura do "pergunte já sabendo a resposta". Eu mesmo já tive casos de apagar perguntas/respostas ou nem perguntar para não ter risco de ser negativado sem sentido ou "tomar nos dedos" dos gurus que tem por ai (sem generalizar).

Answer (score 14):

Quando lemos um texto, utilizamos um meio de comunicação no qual não existe entonação de voz, expressões faciais nem linguagem gestual. É complicado inferir coisas como sarcasmo, ironia, condescendência, pedância etc.

Por isso, a menos que haja insultos explícitos ou que você conheça pessoalmente o autor do post, você não tem como saber se a pessoa que lhe dirige a palavra é um anjo, um sociopata, ambas as coisas ou nenhuma das alternativas anteriores. Qualquer julgamento de atitude existe apenas na sua mente.

Some-se a isso o fato de que aqui contribuem pessoas de várias culturas diferentes. Uma forma de escrever que é amistosa em um lugar pode ser ofensiva em outro e vice-versa... E por mais que nos esforcemos para nos comunicar de forma neutra, cada um sempre carregará um jeito próprio e característico de sua própria personalidade.

Eu comecei a pensar nessas coisas quando havia somente o Stack Overflow matriz. Alguns dos usuários mais participativos por lá são fofos e delicados como um cacto. Isso em nada diminuia o conteúdo de seus textos, e na verdade sempre achei que o tom deles servia para que as pessoas menos experientes focassem no que deve ser focado em um Stack. Tenho a impressão de que a visão por lá é a mesma que eu tenho: *"se eu não lhe ameacei nem cometi nenhum crime, qualquer problema que você tenha com a forma como eu escrevo é um problema só seu"*.

---

Sério cara. Isso é uma lição de vida.

Se eu fosse me estressar com cada coisa que eu não gosto eu já estaria louco. Insulto por insulto, eu me sinto ofendido (vicariosamente, por todos os programadores) sempre que alguém posta código mal-identado, não coloca exemplo mínimo, não usa o patinho de borracha, não leu a porra do manual. O meu lado sombrio me fala em sonhos que se eu alimentasse o ódio e fosse um ditador essas pessoas nem existiriam, pois eu já teria garantido que os genes que causam esses comportamentos não seguiriam adiante. Xingue a minha mãe mas não tenha essas falhas de caráter.

Mas eu não alimento o meu lado sombrio. Eu tenho ferramentas aqui para lidar com isso. Edição, voto negativo, voto para fechar, sinalização de que o post não é uma resposta. Não encho minha circulação de cortisóides por isso. Não vejo maldade ou malícia em quem não se comporta como eu gostaria.

A rede é justa. Eu me moldo a ela e ela se adapta aos seus usuários. A história mostra que o consenso de formato e eu estamos em concordância.

Da mesma forma, você dispõe das ferramentas para remover o que não deve estar aqui - e recompensar o que deve. Você pode sinalizar conteúdo que considera ofensivo, pode editar perguntas e respostas para remover impropérios, ao mesmo tempo em que vota positivamente pelos comentários e posts úteis. E não precisa encurtar seu tempo na terra, forçar seu coração porque alguém falou algo que você não gostaria de ouvir.

Mas se o seu coração inflama quando você vê *ad hominem* (seja real ou falso positivo), você vai viver mais se se limitar a lugares mais puristas. Mas pense em quanta troca de conhecimento deixará de fazer por aqui.

---

É a mesma coisa na rua. O preço de podermos falar o que quisermos, é ouvir aquilo que nem sempre queremos ouvir.

Comment: Boa resposta. Eu entrei com o ego inflado, cada down vote era um tormento. Como dia a historinha, há uma briga interna entre o lobo bom e o lobo mau, vence o que você alimenta.

Comment: Sem sombra qualquer de dúvida, seu post é exageradamente sábio! +1

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta. Para ser honesto, até em conversas com colegas de equipe, onde é possível inferir sarcasmo e etc através da entonação de voz e gestos, eu acabo tentando não ver maldade (mesmo onde há sarcasmo, por exemplo). Até que a pessoa insulte diretamente, eu prefiro acreditar que ela só está tentando ajudar à maneira dela. Não dizem que pai e mãe briga com os filhos porque se importam e querem que eles **aprendam** e cresçam? É só uma pequena analogia a se refletir.

Answer (score 6):

Eu levantei esse ponto faz um bom tempo aqui:[moderação agressiva: é o que queremos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5348/6036) Na época fui convencido de que o melhor é tentar interpretar os comentários com boas intenções e só depois dessa reflexão pensar se ele foi abusivo ou não.

No entanto, acho que essa reflexão também deve ser feita por quem for postar um comentário: "como será que vão interpretá-lo?", "será que é rude?". Não custa nada e evita muitos problemas.

Com certeza, quando você usa muito o site, você acaba ficando mais "seco" mas isso não é o ideal. Por isso, sempre vale a pena pensar duas vezes. Afinal, o objetivo de todos aqui é que a comunidade cresça e seja cada vez mais útil.

Comment: Curioso aqui pra ouvir sua opinião: por que você acha que quem usa mais tende a ficar mais seco?

Comment: Leonardo, quando você explica pato de borracha, RTFM e exemplo mínimo pela primeira vez, você se sente animado. Você aprende junto com a pessoa com quem você fala. Mas quando a milésima pessoa chega na rede mais conhecida do mundo e já começa por fazer coisa errada porque teve preguiça de ler outros posts e a introdução da ajuda, e você tem que explicar todo o processo pela milésima vez... Você começa a sentir que não vale a pena o esforço.

Comment: No nordeste do Brasil o trânsito é caótico, em especial nas capitais. Quando você dirige por lá você recebe muitas buzinadas. E ninguém gosta de buzinada, principalmente quem acabou de conseguir a habilitação. Pois bem, lá existe um ditado: `buzina não educa, mas tange gente retardada`. (do verbo tanger: "tocar, açoitar, fustigar animais para que andem ou fujam: o boiadeiro tangeu o gado para a invernada.") Acho que o sentimento aqui é o mesmo. Votos negativos, fechamento e mensagens duras não educam os novatos, mas os tange. Afinal, se eles não aprenderam observando o site e lendo o help...

Comment: Bom, pelo menos eu não fiquei "seco" na minha forma de se expressar, e eu não sei se isso é uma verdade aqui. Infelizmente eu não posso me responsabilizar pela interpretação de um usuário em relação ao comentário ser considerado "rude".

Comment: @gato, o certo seria "na minha forma de **me** expressar". Desculpe 'aproveitar' seu deslize pra mostrar que as coisas podem parecer rudes pra quem recebe e para quem está de fora. Tem usuários que convivem aqui há mais tempo e entre si dispensam a 'pompa' e quem está observando pode sentir-se incomodado. No mais, uma carinha feliz demonstra minha intenção :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie tuche! :P Este é o ponto. Para certas coisas não existe uma linha dizendo o que é rude ou não, isso me soa até um pouco subjetivo as vezes.

Comment: @PapaCharlie até carinha feliz pode acarretar interpretações ruins, muitas pessoas utilizam para sarcasmo. Não que esse seja o caso aqui, claro, apenas complementando seu ponto de vista, de que até o mais simples e inocentes dos "gestos" podem ser interpretados como ofensa.

Comment: @diegofm, sim, é o fator humano, num dia interpretamos algo de uma forma, outro dia de outra forma... Depende do humor dos dois lados. `if( $person === ';)' // tudo bem rsrsrs )`

Comment: @PapaCharlie interpretei como "erro de sintaxe" :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento rsrs, pra alguns é 'fatal error' sem perdão. É como você disse acima, presumir boa intenção, ler e reler caso tenha soado rude, antes de replicar um comentário.

Comment: @Renan Se buzina funcionasse, o trânsito não era caótico

Comment: @Gabe eu vou além e digo que a buzina só é usada por motivo de o trânsito ser caótico. Em um trânsito perfeito ela não teria motivo de existir. Mas no meio do caos existente, ela diminui a entropia pontualmente em algumas situações. Minha visão é a mesma aqui. Se todo mundo lesse as instruções e fizesse boas perguntas, não precisaríamos de votos negativos e para fechamentos...

Comment: @Renan A solução então é tentar descobrir como se aproximar do trânsito perfeito, ao invés de distribuir mais buzina. Foco na doença, não no sintoma.

Comment: É, a única diferença é que aqui a gente quer mais "carros no nosso trânsito" :) Então, aí eu acho que vale a reflexão com a analogia mesmo: no fantástico mundo de Bob você prefere ouvir uma buzinada ou alguém passar do seu lado e te educar sobre o erro que cometeu?